# How do I send a file to a ftp server via command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, ftp, command-line

I want to send a file to a ftp server using the command line of Windows.  How do I do this?

Comment: What, in the first place, is your OS?

Comment: I dont understand why this is being down voted?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: My OS is windows 7

Comment: @biz it could be downvoted because the question is incomplete, or because it's to broad or not a real question.

Answer (score 2):

```
ftp ftp.someftp.com
cd /pub/somewhere
binary # if you are uploading non-TXT files
passive on
put filetobeuploaded.zip
```

Something along those lines should be enough. `passive on` is needed on some servers. You might not need it.

Comment: put filetobeuploaded.zip  into   ftp ftp.someftp.com

Comment: Don't forget `binary`.  IIRC ftp uses ASCII mode by default, and that could really mess up things like zip files.

Comment: You are right :) Hear that @biz? :)

Answer (score 0):

if it is static, put the commands in a txt file like commands.txt, then call

ftp -s:commands.txt

Keeps it nice and clear, and you can just modify the txt file when needed.